# Pandas DataFrame Return Value from Column Index

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that has values of the different column numbers for another dataframe. Is there a way that I can just return the value from the other dataframe instead of just having the column index.

I basically want to match up the index between the Push and df dataframes. The values in the Push dataframe contain what column I want to return from the df dataframe.

Push dataframe:

```
    0   1
0   1   2
1   0   3
2   0   3
3   1   3
4   0   2
```

df dataframe:

```
    0   1   2   3   4
0   10  11  22  33  44
1   10  11  22  33  44
2   10  11  22  33  44
3   10  11  22  33  44
4   10  11  22  33  44
```

return:

```
    0   1
0   11  22
1   10  33
2   10  33
3   11  33
4   10  22
```

Comment: Could you rephrase your question, and what exactly are you expecting in the output, also how are the two dataframes related to each other?

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with  `np.take` ; However this function works on the flattened array. push must be shift like that :

```
 In [285]: push1 = push.values+np.arange(0,25,5)[:,None]
 In [229]: pd.DataFrame(df.values.take(push1))
```

**EDIT**

No, I just reinvent `np.choose` :

```
In [24]: df
Out[24]: 
    0   1   2   3   4
0   0   1   2   3   4
1  10  11  12  13  14
2  20  21  22  23  24
3  30  31  32  33  34
4  40  41  42  43  44

In [25]: push
Out[25]: 
   0  1
0  1  2
1  0  3
2  0  3
3  1  3
4  0  2

In [27]: np.choose(push.T,df).T
Out[27]: 
    0   1
0   1   2
1  10  13
2  20  23
3  31  33
4  40  42
```

Comment: it works  only because  lines are equal :( ; must be tuned.

Answer (score 0):

We using `melt` then `replace`  notice (df1 is your push , df2 is your df)

```
df1.astype(str).replace(df2.melt().drop_duplicates().set_index('variable').value.to_dict())
Out[31]: 
    0   1
0  11  22
1  10  33
2  10  33
3  11  33
4  10  22
```